# каков размер типа double на 32-разрядной машине?

Tags: память, типы-данных, железо

Всегда считал что double - это 8 байт.
Но недавно задумался, а как он может быть 8 байт на 32-разрядном компьютере?
Что же получается, одно число в двух регистрах хранится?

Comment: XMM/SSE/AVX регистры имеют далеко не 32 бита...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, и в них как раз происходят операции с плавающей точкой?

Comment: В том числе операции с плавающей точкой. Может быть еще вычисление на обычных инструкциях, компилер может и такой код сделать

Comment: От архитектуры сильно зависит. на x86 изначально было устройство FPU (до 80486DX выполнялся в отдельном корпусе x87). У него есть свой набор команд, И именно его и считали обычным способом работы с double. Он включает 8 регистров st0-st7 по 64 бита

Answer (score 2):

В соответствии со стандартом IEEE-754, то, что Вы называете double - это число удвоенной точности, ВСЕГДА 64 бита без вопросов (правда название в разных языках может быть разным, не обязательно double). Оно не обязано храниться в регистрах, а может храниться в памяти. Операции над этими числами выполняются НЕ в регистрах общего назначения (кроме специальных трюков, и то редко). Есть ещё регистры xmm, в которые вмещается по 2 таких числа и в которых обычно компилятор старается затолкать все действия. Разрядность процессора при этом не играет никакой роли, потому что нет смысла хранить в регистрах общего назначения числа с плавающей точкой (разве только не для каких-то трюков с ними). Плавающая арифметика и целочисленная - это совсем разные сферы, и спутывать их будет большой ошибкой. Ранее устаревший ныне тип long double вообще был 80 бит, сейчас ряд известных компиляторов его вообще не поддерживает. Числа этого типа обрабатывались на FPU, стек которого мог сохранять до 10 таких чисел. В Стандарте ещё есть числа учетверённой точности - 128 бит, но они мало где поддерживаются аппаратно, так же как и числа половинной точности - 16 бит (есть на ARM в двух вариантах - стандартные и расширенные).

Изучение таких чисел можно начать с простейших источников, типа [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).

Comment: Ещё один полезный ресурс, в котором есть, в том числе, обсуждение [плавающей арифметики](http://ru.exploringcomputerarithmetic.org/articles/fp/IEEE-754/basics/).